# May I replace "me" with "myself" in the sentence: I had brought suits with me?

Tags: pronouns, reflexive-pronouns

May I replace **me** with **myself** in the sentence:

> I had brought suits with **me**?

1. May I replace it?
2. If I can, what's the difference between them?

Comment: Your sentence does not make sense, unless you brought the cupboard with you from somewhere else, which seems unlikely.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  Yes, so I deleted **in the cupcoard**.

Comment: _Brought with me_  is fine. There is no reason to use _myself_, although some native speakers over-use it because they think it sounds better.

Comment: But the subject is **I**, so **myself** is better. Is there a such saying? @KateBunting

Comment: I would say that 'myself' is always a mistake unless reflexive action is being discussed.

Comment: Yes, the subject is **I**, but the object is **suits**. You are not doing anything **to** yourself.

Comment: Hmm. You can dance a dance with yourself, but you bring a book with you. Something's different there. It seems to me when spoken I can't emphasize the word "me" in "bring with me", it always has to be less emphasized than "with", because there's no special distinction being introduced by "me".

Comment: @DanGetz So, except for **with**, we can use **myself**. Am I right?

Comment: @Y.zeng no, that's the thing, that's why I'm unsure what's happening in these phrases. You can dance with yourself, and that uses "with". Another aspect of "bring with me": you can bring something with you, you can bring something with someone else, but if you want to emphasize that you didn't bring it with someone else, you don't say "with myself", you say "by myself". I have no idea why this is the case. I guess "bring with me" and "bring with someone" are different somehow.

Comment: To be fair, you would normally say "dance by yourself", I just mean "with yourself" seems to also be grammatical. Maybe I'm wrong about that?

Comment: So **with** is an exception? @DanGetz

Comment: @Y.zeng I think you just asked me that, and I said I don't know for certain, sorry! Hope someone else can help you more.

Comment: @DanGetz Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DanGetz - this site discourages answers or comments of the "I don't really know" type.

Answer (score 1):

1. **No** - "me" is correct in your example.
2. 'Myself' is a *reflexive pronoun*, used for self-reference. Generally, their use is to *clarify* identity. For example:

> I bought the book *for myself*.

You could just simply say "I bought the book" and let people *assume* that you bought it to read, and not as a gift to give to someone else. Adding "for myself" adds *clarity* about *who* the book is for.

In your example of "I brought the suits with me", adding "with me" does add some clarity but *not with respect to identity*. If you simply said "I brought the suits", it is clear *who* brought the suits but arguably it is not clear *where* you brought them. "With me" is an idiomatic way of saying that they are in your possession.

If in doubt about the use of me/myself, test it with 'you/yourself' as there seems to be far less confusion about this. "Did *you* bring the suits with *you*?" is correct.

Comment: I bought the book for myself. I brought the suits with myself. Do you feel they are the same? So, why can't I use **myself**?